# Windows 10: Different Backgrounds for virtual desktops

Tags: windows-10

How to get different background images for different virtual Desktops in Windows 10?

I know how to change it for two different monitors, but is it also possible for virtual desktops?

Answer (score 28):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible yet. You can, however, use a third party app, such as [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de), which allows you to set individual backgrounds for each desktop.

Comment: I can't believe this...

Comment: I would allso surgest display fusion

Comment: Will MS ever add this feature to Windows 10?

Comment: Does that even work in Windows 10?  It doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: If you're referring to Dexpot, my experience shows that it will work in general, but I'm finding that if I'm using Dexpot in Win10 (I used it for years on Win7), I hit numerous "spinning circle" periods that last a minute or more, and which occur several times a day. It seems like this happens mostly in Firefox. After stopping Dexpot and using the Win 10 VDM, I no longer see this (but suffer from the lack of Dexpot's features).

Comment: It's worth nothing that the last "News" update on the Dexpot website is from February 2016 and says "Long time no hear! Thank you for sending in your feedback regarding compatibility issues with Windows 10 - we're aware of them. An update will follow."

Answer (score 4):

This guy wrote a program to do this, basically, check the background and change accordingly in certain interval. Not elegant, but seems the only working solution for now...
'Basically, it uses APIs to get the current desktop and checks every small period of time to see if it has changed. If it detects a change, it sets the wallpaper to the appropriate one (configured by the user in the main screen).'
[Setting The Virtual Desktop Background (In Windows 10)](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1030472/Setting-The-Virtual-Desktop-Background-In-Windows)

Comment: Unfortunately this has not (yet) been updated to work with the Anniversary Update

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 3):

Interesting note: this feature -- different wallpapers for different desktops -- exists in (Linux) Kubuntu 14.04 but unfortunately *not* in later versions of Kubuntu. That change has been the subject of ferocious controversy in the Kubuntu community, and relates to the fact that newer editions of Kubuntu are oriented about "activities".  People keep proposing workarounds, with lukewarm reception.  I haven't tried any of them, but I get the impression that they all have drawbacks.  For myself, I've stuck with 14.04 because of this.  Alas, 14.04 will lose maintenance in 2019, a year that is fast approaching.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an v.old thread but I kept coming across it when looking for answers

Not a proper solution but what I did & think is not a bad option: Windows Stickies

I use Windows 10 OEM Stickies anyway and found you can drag a particular sticky to whichever virtual desktop you want.
So can have a nice bright sticky with a heading or whatever that indicates which screen you are on. I was using a .txt doc but not pretty.
Of course it takes up some display space but I guess you would not see a background anyway if a windows fully open.

Annoyed I did not think of this earlier, I have a sticky's for work and many for personal and fed up hiding the business one, so 2 birds with one stone.

On full restart do have to re-drag from task view as they all open on 1 virtual DT but no hardship. Sleep, they stay where they are.

Answer (score 1):

An AHK solution, that has some extra neat features: https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer

A GIF of the program at work: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-set-different-wallpapers-for-virtual-desktops-in-windows-10/

Comment: No longer works in windows 10 - Project seems deprecated as GitHub is read only now.

Answer (score 1):

Try VirtualDesktopManager (https://github.com/m0ngr31/VirtualDesktopManager).  It is portable and released in zip file format.  Simply unpack to whatever folder you desired and launch VirtualDesktopManager.exe.

I downloaded release 1.9.0 and it works well on all 4 virtual desktops I have.  There is a minor delay on background repaint when switching between virtual desktops.

Comment: There doesnt seem to be any mention in the documentation about switching wallpapers with this script. Could you please answer the question about usingg different wallpapers for each destop?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Once launched, you should find a toolbar icon.  Right-click on the icon and select "settings" allows you to choose different wallpapers.  Once set, use <Ctrl>+<Alt>+{ right or left arrow key }  to switch between desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [VirtuaWin](https://virtuawin.sourceforge.io/) (free, opensource) and installing the [module](https://virtuawin.sourceforge.io/?page_id=50) VirtuaWallpaperPlus to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, worked great for me:

https://wizardsoft.nl/products/wsvirtualdesktoptool

From their site:

> "This utility lets you switch between multiple virtual desktops and
> move windows instantly with keyboard shortcuts. It also allows you to
> configure different wallpapers for each virtual desktop. When you
> switch to another virtual desktop, its associated wallpaper is
> automatically shown. To configure different wallpapers, just do so
> through the usual Windows Background settings
> (ms-settings:personalization-background)."

Answer (score 0):

This is possible since update Windows 21H2 in October 2021.

> ... head to Settings > Personalization > Background to set this up.
> Simply left-clicking a background here will set it as the background
> for only your current virtual desktop.

https://www.howtogeek.com/719126/windows-10s-virtual-desktops-are-getting-custom-wallpaper-backgrounds/

Comment: Have you tried it? On Windows 10 21H2?

Comment: @MarkSowul I'm running Windows 11 Pro 21H2 and it's working well

Comment: Yeah, apparently it only works on Windows **11** 21H2, not Windows **10** 21H2