# Naming Windows 10 virtual Desktops

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

Since we know that in [Windows 10: Different Backgrounds for virtual desktops](https://superuser.com/q/952810/32029) are not supported, what about at least naming them, and display a small "overlay" text at switch time, or in the task bar at the bottom of each virtual desktop?

**Can I give my Windows 10 virtual desktop descriptive names, instead of just numbers?**

Currently the are named only "Desktop1" etc..

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works for you -

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-to-let-you-rename-virtual-desktops-heres-how/

You may need to have a `Windows 10` build which is recent enough.

If you are open to using paid apps from `MS Store`, you may also consider this -

https://mspoweruser.com/app-superpowers-windows-10s-virtual-desktops-now-available-microsoft-store/

Comment: I have Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363, but it does not work.